# C++ template partial specialization question

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm having compile time trouble with the following code:

```
  template <typename T, 
            template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> > class C>
  bool is_in(const C<T>& a, const C<T>& b);

  template <typename T, std::vector> // HERE
  bool is_in(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
  {
    return false; // implementation tbd
  }

...

vector<int> a, b;

cout << is_in(a,b) << endl;
```

The error message is (on the line marked "HERE"):

```
error: 'std::vector' is not a type
```

(of course, I *have* included vector from std!). Any suggestion? I fiddled with it for a while, but I'm getting to the point where I could use some help :-) I need to partially specialize the initial template declaration so that I can have the compiler switch implementations depending on the actual type of the container C (there will be a is_in for sets, one for vectors, one for ranges..., with different algorithms each time).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partial specialization  of a function template is not allowed by the Standard.

A simple solution is : use overload.

```
template <typename T> 
bool is_in(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
  return false; // implementation tbd
}
```

This is overloaded function template. Its NOT *partial* specialization.

Or, you could do this:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename C>
    struct S
    {
        static bool impl(const C & a, const C & b)
        {
            //primary template
            //...
        }
    }
    template<typename T>
    struct S<T, std::vector<T> >
    {
        static bool impl(const std::vector<T> & a, const std::vector<T> & b)
        {
            //partial specialization for std::vector
            return false;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T,  template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> > class C>
bool is_in(const C<T>& a, const C<T>& b)
{
   return detail::S<T, C<T> >::impl(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Booouuuhhh! :-) Of course, that will curtail my efforts - I'll have to roll out a function object...

Answer (score 1):

Function template partial specialization is **not** allowed. In any case you're not using the template specialization syntax, you're actually writing an additional overload. Try this instead:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_in(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    return false; // implementation tbd
}
```

If partial specialization *were* allowed, it would look like this instead:

```
template <typename T> // std::vector is not a template parameter,
                      // so we wouldn't put it here
bool is_in<T, std::vector>(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
// instead, it'd appear ^ here, when we're specializing the base template
{
    return false; // implementation tbd
}
```

Comment: That results in: error: function template partial specialization 'is_in<T, template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector>' is not allowed quite explicitly.

Comment: @Frank Don't just copy & paste the code. I've added emphasis in the post though.

Comment: @Frank My point was that *of course* it doesn't work. That's what I said.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just supplying the error message you get for education.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works (as template templates are always a trouble to my mind), but what about just trying

```
template <typename T>
bool is_in(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    ...
}
```

as it's a specialization.

**EDIT:** Others have clarified on this already, but I'll add it for completeness. The above code is actually an overload and not a partial specialization, but partial function specializations aren't allowed anyway.

Comment: It is NOT a specialization. Its overloaded function template.

Comment: @Nawaz Oh yes, you're right. Luc's answer clarifies on the syntax differences, but partial specializations aren't allowed anyway, as you say in your answer, too.